# Using zend studio with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, zend-studio

I want to use Zend Studio for a project built on CodeIgniter. But I want to be able to use the debugging functionality of Zend. Because of that, I cant seem to get the debugger to work properly cause it doesnt "understand" codeigniter. So, in order for the setup to work, do I need to install Zend server, so that the debugging is done serverside? Can someone explain this to me a bit? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Iraklis said, the forum had the answer, to save people some extra searching, here's  what worked for me:

### Step 1

add:

```
<?php
class CI_Controller {
    /**
     *
     * @var CI_DB_active_record
     */
    public $db;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Loader
     */
    public $load;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Output
     */
    public $output;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Email
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Session
     */
    public $session;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Config
     */
    public $config;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Benchmark
     */
    public $benchmark;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Calendar
     */
    public $calendar;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Cart
     */
    public $cart;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Encrypt
     */
    public $encrypt;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Upload
     */
    public $upload;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Form_validation
     */
    public $form_validation;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_FTP
     */
    public $ftp;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Table
     */
    public $table;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Image_lib
     */
    public $image_lib;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Input
     */
    public $input;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Language
     */
    public $lang;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Pagination
     */
    public $pagination;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Trackback
     */
    public $trackback;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Parser
     */
    public $parser;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Typography
     */
    public $typography;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Unit_test
     */
    public $unit;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_URI
     */
    public $uri;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_User_agent
     */
    public $agent;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Xmlrpcs
     */
    public $xmlrpcs;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Xmlrpc
     */
    public $xmlrpc;

    /**
     *
     * @var CI_Zip
     */
    public $zip;

}
```

and

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Enter description here ...
 * @return CI_Controller
 */
function get_instance()
{

}
```

into files included by your project (create a new file for each just to be safe and make sure it's included in build path)

### Step 2

Rebuild to make sure eclipse/zend is aware of the change.

### The inconvenient truth:

Unfortunately this won't work for views variables, only for `$this->` calls, because Codeigniter uses `arrays` to store `variable names`, so eclipse/zend would need to be running the code in order to see them. And to make things even harder to detect automatically, this is done cross-file and the filename is set using a variable.

here is one example:

in **views/controllers/file.php** you put:

```
$data['foo']='foo text';
$this->load->view("foo",$data);  //"foo" is the filename without the .php extension
```

in **views/foo.php** you get:

```
echo $foo;
//outputs: "foo text"
```

But this is just the way codeigniter works.

source:
https://github.com/scoumbourdis/codeigniter-autocomplete/tree/master/application/libraries/fake

full tutorial:
http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-and-eclipse-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to search  [codeigniter's forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/). There are a few threads there discussing Zend integration.